# Add error bar to a single column in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pred': [10, 9.5, 9.8], 'Actual': [10.2, 9.9, 9.1], 'STD': [0.1, 0.2, 0.6]})

    Pred    Actual  STD
0   10.0    10.2    0.1
1   9.5     9.9     0.2
2   9.8     9.1     0.6
```

I want to make a bar plot with error bars using `STD` only on the `Pred` column, and not on the `Actual` column. So far I have this:

```
df.plot.bar(yerr='STD', capsize=4)
```

[image]

but this adds the error bars on both `Actual` and `Pred`. Is there a straight forward way to tell Pandas to add the erorr bar to a single column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
errors=df.STD.to_frame('Pred')
df[['Actual','Pred']].plot.bar(yerr=errors, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I ended up using `df.drop('STD', axis=1).plot.bar(yerr={'Pred': df.STD})` so that I don't have to specify `['Actual', 'Pred']`, which I was trying to avoid.